# Disable/Block jpg Images

Tags: image, block, jpeg

I would like to know if there is any way to block/disable jpg images filetypes

I am building a gadget for windows which shows the rss of a site but i would like to disable/block jpg images from the flyout which shows the description of the article

Comment: what is your "gadget" built in? and or running on?

Comment: javascript and html windows sidebar gadget